# SQL Count Report Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following table in SQL Server.

Test.

```
id  | Author| Ext
----+-------+--------
01  | Bill  | txt
02  | Tom   | pdf
03  | Bill  | doc
04  | Alex  | txt
05  | Alex  | pdf
06  | Tom   | pdf
```

I want following to be output based on id.

```
  | Author| txt | pdf | doc
  --------+-----+-----+-----
  | Bill  |  1  |  0  |  1
  | Tom   |  0  |  2  |  0
  | Alex  |  1  |  1  |  0
```

Can anyone suggest me query for the same?

Comment: You want a pivot: http://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot

Comment: Where do you want to show this? In an app or Website? Then just use the programming language at hand and loop through the data. Or in a Report created with a report engine? Or how else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `Ext` column value to be dynamic, you can use dynamic query string.

Example :

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (id int, author varchar(100), ext varchar(3));



INSERT INTO Table1
    (id, author, ext)
VALUES
    (1, 'Bill', 'txt'),
    (2, 'Tom', 'pdf'),
    (3, 'Bill', 'doc'),
    (4, 'Alex', 'txt'),
    (5, 'Alex', 'pdf'),
    (6, 'Tom', 'pdf')
```

**Query 1**:

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR
DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @MyField VARCHAR(30)

SET @SQLString = 'SELECT author ' 

 SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
 SELECT ext FROM Table1 group by ext

OPEN @MyCursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
    INTO @MyField

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLString = @SQLString + ',sum(case [ext] when ''' + @MyField  + ''' then 1 else 0 end) as ' + @MyField 
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor 
      INTO @MyField 
    END


CLOSE @MyCursor 
DEALLOCATE @MyCursor 

SET @SQLString = @SQLString + ' FROM Table1 group by author'

 EXECUTE sp_executesql  @SQLString
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1c1b0/65/0)**:

```
| author | doc | pdf | txt |
|--------|-----|-----|-----|
|   Alex |   0 |   1 |   1 |
|   Bill |   1 |   0 |   1 |
|    Tom |   0 |   2 |   0 |
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select [Author],
sum(case [Ext] when 'txt' then 1 else 0 end) as [txt],
sum(case [Ext] when 'pdf' then 1 else 0 end) as [pdf],
sum(case [Ext] when 'doc' then 1 else 0 end) as [doc]
from [your_table_name]
group by [Author];
```

Comment: actually I have so many records. So is there any dynamic way?

Comment: @Hardik Viradiya: It doesn't matter whether you have, say, four records or six million records. The query is the same.

Comment: @HardikViradiya : If the `Ext` column values are not known, then you need to do it in a dynamic way

Answer (score 0):

CASE expression should be used as follow:

```
SELECT
    author,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ext = 'txt' THEN 1 END) as txt,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ext = 'pdf' THEN 1 END) as pdf,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN ext = 'doc' THEN 1 END) as doc
FROM myTable
GROUP BY author
```

Comment: actually I have so many records. So is there any dynamic way?

Comment: Either remove the `ELSE 0` (or replace it with `ELSE null`) or use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Use below pivot method :

```
 CREATE TABLE #Temp ( id VARCHAR(10) , Author VARCHAR(10), Ext VARCHAR(10) )

 INSERT INTO  #Temp ( id , Author , Ext ) 
 SELECT 01,'Bill','txt' UNION ALL
 SELECT 02,'Tom','pdf' UNION ALL
 SELECT 03,'Bill','doc' UNION ALL
 SELECT 04,'Alex','txt' UNION ALL
 SELECT 05,'Alex','pdf' UNION ALL
 SELECT 06,'Tom','pdf' 

 SELECT *
 FROM 
  (
    SELECT Author , Ext 
    FROM #Temp
  ) A
 PIVOT 
 ( 
     COUNT(Ext) FOR Ext IN ([txt],[pdf],[doc])
 )   A
```

Comment: Thanks Mansoor it work but how to escape [ ] brackets if there is any values in IN
Eg: Ext IN ( [tct[] )

Comment: Can you provide sample data

Comment: ok. Got it. I just need to replace ending brackets with two brackets. and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using PIVOT

```
with a as
(select 1 as a_id,'abc' as author,'txt' as ext from dual
union
select 2 ,'pqr' as author,'pdf' as ext from dual
union
select 3,'abc' as author,'doc' as ext from dual
union
select 4,'lmn' as author,'txt' as ext from dual
union
select 5,'pqr' as author,'pdf' as ext from dual
)
select * 
from 
  ( select *
    from a
  ) pivot 
  ( count(ext) 
    for ext in 
    ('txt' as txt_ext,'pdf' as pdf_ext,'doc' as doc_ext)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

For this option, i think using pivot is the best way;

```
Select * FROM(
    Select Authot,Ext,Count(Ext) CountExt FROM #temp Group By Authot,Ext
    ) t
    PIVOT(
            SUM(CountExt) 
            FOR EXt IN ([pdf],[txt],[doc])) as pvt
```